# Perl Calculator, Printing non-complex numbers, and divide by 0 error

Tags: perl

I'm not sure how to apply this prompt criteria to my code:
For example:
root 2 64 
- 9 7
The examples above would yield 8 and 2.  You program should end when the word exit is typed as an operator.  Your program should NOT handle complex numbers but rather display an error message (ie. “Please wait for version 2.0 of PerlCalculator”).  In addition, your program should display an error for division by 0, etc.

Here is my code thus far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;


print "enter a symbol operation symbol to and two numbers to make a calculation";

my $input = <STDIN>;

my ($operation, $x, $y) = split ' ', $input;
#print "$operation\n"."$x\n"."$y\n";
if($operation eq "+"){
my $z = ($x + $y);
print "$z\n";
print "$operation\n"."$x\n"."$y\n";
}
elsif ( $operation eq "-"){
my $z = ($x - $y);
print "$z\n";
print "$operation\n"."$x\n"."$y\n";
}
elsif ( $operation eq "*"){
my $z = $x * $y;
print "$z\n";
print "$operation\n"."$x\n"."$y\n";
}
elsif ( $operation eq "/"){
my $z = $x / $y;
print "$z\n";
print "$operation\n"."$x\n"."$y\n";
}
elsif ( $operation eq "%"){
my $z = $x % $y;
print "$z\n";
print "$operation\n"."$x\n"."$y\n";
}
elsif ($operation eq "pow"){
my $z = $x ** $y;
print "$operation\n"."$x\n"."$y\n";
print "$z\n";
}
elsif ($operation eq "root"){
my $z =  $x ** (1/2);
my $i =  $y ** (1/2);
print "$z\n";
print "$i\n";
print "$operation\n"."$x\n"."$y\n"; 
}
else{
print "$operation\n"."$x\n"."$y\n";
print " you messed up"."$operation\n/"; 
}
```

The print strings are in there for troubleshooting so that I can see if the `if`statement is taking the correct integer

Comment: 1. You don't check for zero in denominator in division operator 2. You don't have exit operator being processed, so your program will without end

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Handling division by zero error.

```
elsif ( $operation eq "/" ) {
    eval {
        my $z = $x / $y;
        print "$z\n";
        print "$operation\n" . "$x\n" . "$y\n";
    };

    if ($@) {
        warn "Error: Division by zero!!";
    }
}
```